# C++ ERROR about count_if: expected primary-expression before

Tags: c++, oop, templates, stl, stl-algorithm

```
vector<T> m;
```

is a private member in a template class.

```
template<class T>
bool Matrix_lt<T> :: isNotZero(T val) {
    return val != 0;
}
```

is a private function in the same template class.

```
template<class T>
int Matrix_lt<T> :: calL0Norm() {
    int count = count_if(m.begin(), m.end(), isNotZero<T>);//ERROR
}
```

is a public function in the same template class.

ERROR: expected primary-expression before '>' token.
Why??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isNotZero<T>` is a member function, so it has an implicit first parameter for `this`. You need a unary functor, so you will need to use `std::bind`, to bind `this` as the first parameter.

You also need to refer to the function as `&Matrix::isNotZero<T>`. So,

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto f = std::function<bool(const T&)> f = std::bind(&Matrix::isNotZero<T>, 
                                                     this, _1);
```

and use `f` as the functor in `count_if`.

Alternatively, use a lambda:

```
int count = count_if(m.begin(), m.end(), 
                     [this](const T& val) { return this->isNotZero<T>(val);});
```

Answer (score 1):

`isNotZero` is a member function. You cannot use this like that. Use lambda:

```
template<class T>
int Matrix_lt<T> :: calL0Norm() {
    int count = count_if(m.begin(), 
                         m.end(), 
                         [this](T const & val) { return this->isNotZero(v);} );
}
```

Or use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Answer (score 0):

There're two problems here.

1. From your definition, `isNotZero` is not a template function, it is a member function of the template class.

   You cannot refer to a non-template function with template argument.
   Use `int count = count_if(m.begin(), m.end(), isNotZero);`
2. `isNotZero` is a non-static member function. You cannot pass a member function like that.

   I think it's okay to make `isNotZero` as a static member function in this case.